# Closure of the interior

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

It is not true in general that in a topological space, the closure of the interior of a set $A$ is the closure of $A$. This seems to be true, however, if $A$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the usual topology. This property seems to assert that $A$ is somewhat "well-behaved", but what is the name of this property?

Comment: If you take the segment $[(0,0),(0,1)]\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, it's interior is empty and it's closure is not empty, but this segment is convex.

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=closure+interior+convex+set&source=bl&ots=p9qWXtg-OB&sig=nd3mQ5f9M9dvtk_F1J6Mco90-fg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MiQJUfyzApHc8ATg44CwCw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=closure%20interior%20convex%20set&f=false) for the correct statement. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure?lq=1) post may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the special case when $A$ is closed, it is called a *regular closed set*. [This article](http://planetmath.org/RegularOpenSet.html) discusses the dual notion of a regular open set; the properties listed there are easy to dualize. The word "regular" is overused, of course.

I do not know any established term for  general sets with this property. I'd simply say "a set with dense interior".