# $ \text{int}(A) = \text{int(cl}(A))$, where $A$ is convex

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

How can one prove that $ \text{int}(A) = \text{int(cl}(A))$, where $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex?

Comment: This is not duplicate. It is different problem.

Comment: Also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7376/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since ${\rm cl}(A)\supseteq A$, clearly ${\rm int}({\rm cl}(A))\supseteq {\rm int}(A)$. A point $p$ in ${\rm int}({\rm cl}(A))$ is surrounded by some open ball $B$ of points in ${\rm cl}(A)$.  Pick $n+1$ points $q_1$, $\dots$, $q_{n+1}$ that form the vertices of a regular $n$-simplex, contained in $B\subseteq {\rm cl}(A)$, with $p$ at its center.  For points $q'_1$, $\dots$, $q'_{n+1}\in A$ such that each $q'_i$ is sufficiently close to the corresponding $q_i$, $p$ will also be in the interior of the simplex with vertices $q'_1$, $\dots$, $q'_{n+1}$.  Then, since $A$ is convex, $A$ completely contains the interior of this simplex, so $p\in {\rm int}(A)$.  Therefore ${\rm int}({\rm cl}(A))\subseteq {\rm int}(A)$.

Comment: +1: Nice. I wonder if it is true in a topological vector space?

Comment: No. For example, let $\ell^1$ be the space of all sequences of reals whose sum is absolutely convergent, with the usual $\ell^1$ norm, and let $A\subseteq \ell^1$ be the set of all sequences which are eventually zero. Then $A$ is convex, dense in $\ell^1$, and has empty interior.

Comment: Very nice example.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $\subseteq$ is trivial.
For $\supseteq$, suppose $x\in \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$.
Then an open ball $B_r(x)$ of radius $r>0$ around $x$ is $\subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)$.
Then for any choice of signs $ e = (e_1,\ldots, e_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n$ and $0<c<\frac r{\sqrt n}$, the point $x+ce=x+(e_1c, \ldots , e_nc)$ is also in this ball, hence in $\operatorname{cl}(A)$.
For each of these $2^n$ points we can find a point $y_e\in A$ with $|x+ce-y_e|<c$.
Note that the $i$th component $(y_e)_i$ of $y_e$ is $>x_i,<x_i$ iff $e_i>0, e_i<0$, respectively.
Let $d=\min_{e,i}\{|(y_e)_i-x_i|\}>0$. 
Consider $x'$ with $|x'-x|<d$.
Assume that $x'$ is not in the convex hull of the $2^n$ points $y_e$, $e\in \{-1,1\}^n$.
Then there exists a nonzero vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\langle y_e-x',v\rangle\le0$ for all $e$.
Consider $e$ with $e_i>0$ if $v_i\ge 0$ and $e_i<0$ if $v_i<0$. Then $\langle y_e-x',v\rangle>0$ because each product $((y_e)_i-x'_i)v_i$ is nonnegative and at least one is positive. 
From this contradiction, we see that $x'$ is in the convex hull of the $y_e$, hence $x'\in A$.
Consequently, $x\in \operatorname{int}(A)$.

Comment: May I ask why such a nonzero $v$ must exists?

Comment: I think this follows from the separating hyperplane theorem between a nonempty closed convex set $C$ (here the convex hull of the $y_e$s) and a point not in $C$