# Convex dense subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is the entire space

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Say we have a convex dense set $X\subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$, does it follow that $X=\Bbb{R}^n$ ?

For $n=1$ it's true because convex sets of real numbers are intervals, and if it's dense then it must be $\Bbb{R}$.
Anyway, it seems more difficult in the general case, perhaps it's false, I don't know.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your idea for $\mathbb{R}$ has a natural generalization to $\mathbb{R}^n$, using simplices in place of the interval.

Comment: @hardmath I am not familiar with this, I will search, thank you.

Comment: In two dimensions the simplex is a triangle (and in one dimension, an interval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question ([Why does a convex set have the same interior points as its closure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure)) shows that the interior of $X $ is the same as the interior of the closure of $X $ (which is all of $\Bbb{R}^n $). Since a set contains it's interior,  we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Using induction over the dimension $n$, it is easy to show that, given any set of $2^n$ points meeting every quadrant of $\Bbb R^n$, the zero vector is in their convex hull.
Let $Q_i$ denote the $i$-th quadrant for $i=1,\dots,2^n$. Assume $a$ is a point in $\Bbb R^n$. Since $a+Q_i$ is open, we can pick a point $x_i$ from $X\cap(a+Q_i)$. Now since $a$ is in the convex hull of these $x_i$ and $X$ is convex, $a$ must be in $X$.

Answer (score -3):

Let $x \in X$ so we can choose three points that $x$ is inside the triangle(Or in hider dimentions $n+1$ points). We can proxsimate dots from $X$ that $x$ is still in the "triangle". So because $X$ is convex $x \in X$. We proved that $X= \mathbb{R}^n$. Q.E.D

Comment: -1. Your idea is probably correct but the answer is so poorly formulated that it is impossible to understand it. If you rephrase it so that it is precise and clear I will reverse my downvote with pleasure.