# Is every convex cone a subset of a half space?

Tags: analysis, statistics, convex-analysis, machine-learning, convex-geometry

I have come across a proof for this statement(link to paper at end), which however I do not understand. It makes use of Lemma 5.5, which I've also included.

Lemma 1. The interior of the complement of a proper convex set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-empty.

Theorem: Every proper  convex cone $K \neq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a subset of a half-space.

Proof:

By lemma 1, we know $K^c$ has a non-empty interior. If there is a vector $v \in K^c$, such that $-v \in K^c$ as well, then it is possible to take the conic hull of $\{v\}$ and $K$. After this operation, $-v$ cannot belong to conic-hull $(\{v\} \cup K)$. Therefore, a convex cone $K$ can always be expanded unless there are no vectors $v \in K^c$ such that $-v \in K^c$.

The fact that for every vector in $K^c$ we have its opposite inside $K$ makes $-K^c$ identical to int $(K)$ which means $K^c$ is now itself a convex cone. As a result, the boundary $\operatorname{cl}(K) \cap \operatorname{cl}\left(K^c\right)$ is the intersection of two convex cones and is therefore convex.
The boundary or the set of points $\{v \in K \mid-v \in K\}$ is closed under scalar action on top of being closed under addition by virtue of being a convex cone. This means that the boundary is an $(n-1)$-dimensional vector subspace, i.e. a hyperplane. $\blacksquare$

I understand that we are trying, in this proof, to show that $K^c$ is also a convex cone, but I don't understand how we get there. Would very much appreciate your help!

link: original paper here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.05423.pdf

Comment: In that sentence, delete 'it is possible' . This is just bad wording: you can take conic hulls whatever you like. In some/most cases, this will not make sense or will not be helpful.

Comment: Also their proof of Lemma 5.5 looks fishy. The claim is false for infinite-dimensional vector spaces (take a dense convex set) but the proof does not use finite-dimensional arguments.

Comment: I agree the proof of Lemma 5.5 is fishy. Even ignoring the typo about "open balls around $v$" vs "around $0$", the argument doesn't make sense. In the first paragraph, they seem to assume that the negation of "there exists a $w$ such that $v + w \in C$ and $v - w \in C$" is, or implies, "for all $w$, we have $v + w \notin C$", but that's wrong. The statement of the lemma is true, though. Welcome to MSE by the way!

Comment: Thank you @IzaakvanDongen! How do you know the statement is true? I'd be very grateful if you could refer me to another proof.

Comment: It seems that the rough idea of the proof for 5.6 is "if $K$ is a proper convex cone and $v, -v$ are both in $K^c$, then $K$ can be extended to a larger proper convex cone. So assume WLOG that $K$ has been extended as much as possible (not justified in much detail! but you can make this assumption), so cannot be extended any more. Then the boundary must be a hyperplane (also missing some justification)". There are definitely some skipped steps and some sloppiness - I don't see why $-K^c$ must be identical to $\mathrm{int}(K)$ from what they've written, for example.

Comment: Another way to state Lemma 5.5 is "a dense convex subset of $\Bbb R^n$ must be all of $\Bbb R^n$", as daw observed. This is discussed eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1707225/473276). hardmath's comment in that thread is the most intuitive reason to me!