# Properties of convex set (interior, closure)

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $A$ convex set

$(1)$ If $y\in\bar{A}$ and  $x\in\text{int}(A)$ then $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in\text{int}(A)$, $\forall\,0<\lambda<1$

$(2)$ $\bar{A}$ and $\text{int}(A)$ are convex sets.

My teacher said (without showing how) that $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be used to show that

If $\text{int}(A)\neq \phi$ then $\bar{A}=\text{closure}(\text{int}(A))$ and $\text{int}(A)=\text{int}(\bar{A})$

But I am not sure why this is true. Does anyone know how this is true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a convex set have the same interior points as its closure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure)

Answer (score 0):

$\bar{A}=\text{closure}(\text{int}(A))$ by (1) you can show that y is a limit of points in the interior as $ \lambda $ goes to 1. That is true only if the interior is non empty.
For the secend equlity think of $\bar{A} / \partial \bar{A}$ what are the set members(think of (1) once more)?