# Convex set contains line segment between that connects its interior and closure is contained in its interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure), one of the answer (by Dimitris) uses the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a convex set. Suppose $\text{Int}A \ne \emptyset$. If $x \in \text{Int} A$ and $y \in \text{Cl}A$, then $[x, y) \subset \text{Int}A$, where
$$
[x,y) := \{y+\lambda(x-y)\mid\lambda\in(0,1]\}.
$$

(I changed the statement in the case of $\mathbb{R}^N$ since it suffices for my purpose.)

I am having trouble in proving this lemma. Here is my attempt.

> Pick any $x \in \text{Int} A$ and $y \in \text{Cl}A$. If $y \in \text{Int}A$, then the result follows because $A$ is convex and thus $\text{Int}A$ is as well. Suppose $y \in \text{Bdry}A:=\text{Cl}A \setminus \text{Int}A$. Pick any $z \in [x,y)$. Then, there exists $\lambda\in(0,1]$ such that $z = y + \lambda(x-y)$.  If $z \notin \text{Int}A$, then $z\in  \text{Bdry}A$ since $z \in \text{Cl}A$ by the convexity of $A$ and $\text{Cl} A$.

Although it is intuitively clear that $z,y\in\text{Bdry}A$ is a contradiction, how can I prove it?

Comment: Why is there suddenly "there exists $\lambda\in(0,1]$ such that $z=y+\lambda(x-y)$" when you haven't actually specified $z$ or $\lambda$?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry, I forgot one sentence. I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: assume also $y\in A$.
Since $x \in \text{Int} A$, there exists $\rho>0$ such that $B_\rho(x)\subset \text{Int} A$.
Let $z = (1-\lambda) y + \lambda x$, $\lambda\in (0,1)$.
Then $B_{\lambda\rho}(z) = z + B_{\lambda\rho}(0) = (1-\lambda)y + \lambda B_\rho(x) \subset A$, so that $z$ is an interior point of $A$.

Case 2: assume $y\in \text{Cl} A$.
The ball $B_{\rho\lambda/(1-\lambda)}(y)$ contains a point $a\in A$; in particular, $a = \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda} u + y$, for some $u\in B_\rho$.
Hence, $z = (1-\lambda) a + \lambda(x-u)\in A$. By case 1, we conclude that $z\in \text{Int} A$.

Comment: Why can you say that $(1-\lambda)y + \lambda B_{\rho} (x) \subset A$? If $y \in A$, then it is clear from the convexity of $A$, but what if $y \in \text{Bdry} A$?

Comment: Right, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume $N\geq 2$ (the case $N=1$ is a lot simpler). Let $r>0$ be such that the closed $r$ ball around $x$ is in $A$. By rotating and shifting, I may assume that $x$ is the origin, and that $y$ lies on the second axis.

Let $z_n$ be a sequence of points in $A$ approaching $y$. We know $p_1:=(r,0,...0)$ and $p_2:=(-r,0,...0)$ are both in $A$, so, by convexity, the triangle $\triangle_n$ with vertices $z_n,p_1,p_2$ lies entirely inside $A$.

Now, let $p$ be a point on $[x,y)$. I think it shouldn't be hard to show that for large enough $n$, the point $p$ must be in the interior of $\triangle_n$, which means it must be in the interior of $A$.

Comment: It seems that if $x$ is the origin and $y$ lies in the first axis, then $y,p_1,p_2$ does not form triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (they are all on the first axis). Moreover, "some details" you mentioned might be essentially the same as my original question.

Comment: @user789100 Sorry, sorry, you're right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I edited the question - is it clear now?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is open and $y \in \text{Bdry} A$. Then, the vertex $y$ is not contained in $A$. In that case, how can you say that $[x,y)$ is in the interior of $A$? I am guessing that proving this point is essentially the same as completing my original attempt...

Comment: @user789100 I'm really sorry, I misread your question. I should have read more carefully. I tried to correct my answer, but there is still a little gap. If it's completely useless to you I can delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer the question. The edited version seems make sense to me. If $y\in\text{Cl}A$, by taking $z^m = B_{1/m} (y) \cap A$ we can obtain the mentioned sequence, and by observing $ \| y - p \| = \lambda \| x - y \| >0$ I think we can obtain the desired result.

Comment: @user789100 Yeah, I think something like that should work.