# Interior of the closure of a convex subset in topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a real topological vector space and $C\subset E$ be a convex subset. Is this true that $\mathrm{Int}(\bar{C})=\mathrm{Int}(C)$? Here $\bar{C}$ is the closure of $C\subset E$ and $\mathrm{Int}$ is the set of interior points.

We know that the statement holds for finite dimensional $E$. cf. [Why does a convex set have the same interior points as its closure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20473/810273) proof in your linked question holds on any topological vector space.

Comment: Yes, it is true (provided that $int C$ is non empty).

Comment: But what if $\mathrm{Int}(C)$ is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is any dense proper subspace of a normed linear space then $Int (M)$ is empty and $int(\overline M)$ is the whole space.

Note that such a subspace $M$ does not exist in a finite dimensional case.